# Unable to set checked box to true from If statement (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input

**Fixed:** Ended up being a typo in the id set of the checkbox input. I left the typo in below for reference. The method does work now. Thank you @Taplar and others!

I've got a series of data points I'm pulling using PHP. That data is populating a modal to make a pseudo-CRUD interface. I can populate text boxes with the pulled data using the below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="recordID" id="recordID" placeholder="Record ID">
```

--

```
<?php  
...
echo '<button type="button" data-recordID="'.$row["RecordID"].'" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">';
```

--

```
 $('#modal-default').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var recordID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-recordID');
    $(this).find('#recordID').val(recordID);
});
```

The above works flawlessly for text boxes. However the form in the modal also consists of several checkboxes (and multi selects but I'll deal with that another day). On the data table, the value of isChecked() is stored to 1 and not checked is 0. So I'm trying to do this:

`<input type="checkbox" class="minimal" name="buildComplete" id"buildComplete">`

```
var buildComplete = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-buildComplete');
if (buildComplete > 0) {
  alert(buildComplete); 

  $('#buildComplete').prop('checked', true);    
} else {
  $('#buildComplete').prop('checked', false); 
}
```

The alert box is telling me the data is coming through correctly, but the box is not checking. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have multiple checkboxes all with the same id? Also, you are using `attr` in the else instead of `prop`.

Comment: Whoops - sorry about the prop / attr switch off. That was me trying to test both and see if either worked. Forgot to change back. I'll edit

Comment: @Kurt I have multiple checkboxes but they all have unique IDs

Comment: @Taplar edited that in for clarification. Thanks

Comment: If that is verbatim, then you have a typo in your id attribute. `id"buildComplete"`

Comment: One thing you could do, is `console.log($("#buildComplete"))` to see if the element is actually there when you try to modify the state.

Comment: @Taplar Well.. I'm ashamed. It really was that simple.  Stare at the technical solution long enough and the bare basics become neglected. Thank you for catching that!